# How to programmatically switch between the phone's keyboards

Tags: android, keyboard

**Summary:**

Trying to develop an app that can switch between the keyboards installed on the phone simply by an if-else statement in the code. Is it possible to do this without rooting the device?

**Please note that:**

My humble research only lead to the ability to do this on rooted devices, otherwise it's not possible and should be done manually by the user - but this is relatively old info (from 2011), so maybe it's possible now?

**Backstory:**

Currently, (with the help of a tutorial), we made an app that is a custom keyboard, and we would like to make the app (on behalf of the user) programmatically switch between this custom keyboard and the phone's default keyboard.

**How we're trying to do it:**

In one of the classes, which implements the KeyboardView, there's this piece of code:

```
public View onCreateInputView() {
    KeyboardView kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
    Keyboard keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
    kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
    return kv;
}
```

It seems that this statement: `kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);` can change the keyboard, so maybe if we add a similar statement but change its argument to reference the default keyboard, then effectively the switch can be made?
If yes then how to reference the default keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can change the switch keyboard programmatically. But you can use keyboard picker.

```
InputMethodManager ime=(InputMethodManager)getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if(ime!=null) {
                   ime.showInputMethodPicker();
                }
```

P.S: this will only show active keyboard set by user in settings

Comment: Thanks, although it's not automatic like what we intended, but I guess this is the closest way.

Comment: Shaz is there any way to programmatically enable a keyboard, even on a rooted device? Also @Nitto did you find a more automated way of doing this or was the inputMethodPicker your best option in the end?